# How to solve "mkv demux error: unable to read KaxCluster during seek, giving up"?

Tags: python, vlc, libvlc, mkv, pafy

I'm making a small music player using pafy and vlc. I get audio with Youtube urls and pass it to vlc. In most cases, it works perfectly. However, sometimes I get the below error on the log, and after that my player crashes.

```
[0000027de1ccce40] main tls client error: connection error: Interrupted function call
[0000027de5eb5b30] mkv demux error: unable to read KaxCluster during seek, giving up
[0000027de5eb5b30] mkv demux error: unable to read KaxCluster during seek, giving up
```

I also got the below minutes ago, but it has been solved by adding 'prefer-insecure'.

```
[000001e269b0b7b0] mp4 demux: Fragment sequence discontinuity detected 1 != 0
```

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56560750/how-to-solve-connection-error-when-trying-to-stream-a-video-from-youtube). In the comment, I saw someone having the same problem as me ,but no one answered that.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: libvlc version? Media Sample? This Q is missing a lot of info

Comment: My libvlc version is 3.0.12118., and my Pafy version is 0.5.5. I cannot provide Media Sample because they are random. Some songs even play well at some time, but throw the error at other time.

Comment: can you reproduce with the VLC mediaplayer app? It would help to provide some samples and repro steps so we can try locally

Comment: The Matroska stream demuxer has a number of options, one of which `--mkv-seek-percent`, might be of use, as it will alter the method of seeking to be based on percent not time